# How to make middle LinearLayout scrollable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

In my code I have 3 LinearLayouts and I want to make the middle one scrollable as to allow for the whole information to be seen.

Currently my code looks like this:

**patient_home_page.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPatientPicture"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_pic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPatientName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Anakin Skywalker" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/infoBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/profileBlock"
        android:layout_above="@id/graphInfoBlock"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDOB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Date of Birth: 26/08/1963" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewGender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Gender: Male" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewMedication"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Current Medication: - " />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewObservation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Observations:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewObservatonsInput"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mollis nulla eu scelerisque ultricies. Etiam varius iaculis purus, et ullamcorper lectus tincidunt et. Nullam vel felis eu dolor condimentum dignissim. Vestibulum in tristique nulla. Mauris elit nibh, ullamcorper in imperdiet sed, luctus vitae nibh. Aliquam nisi nisi, mattis vitae cursus id, dignissim sollicitudin risus. Nam sed egestas mauris, sed scelerisque quam. Morbi sapien turpis, vestibulum at lacus vel, lacinia vehicula elit. Maecenas et lobortis felis. Vivamus elementum ut tortor efficitur iaculis. Vestibulum vestibulum dolor ut urna facilisis eleifend. Nulla gravida mattis eros sit amet molestie. Cras pellentesque sodales tortor, id efficitur neque ultrices at. Pellentesque lacus quam, euismod a dui et, ullamcorper luctus magna. Mauris semper sem vel neque hendrerit, hendrerit elementum nibh sodales." />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/graphInfoBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/graphPressure"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="275dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewGraphValues"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is giving me an error on the layout_above part of the ScrollView which states the following:

"Error:(47, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/graphInfoBlock')."

This is odd because the graphInfoBlock is defined right below. I've tried doing it without the layout_above setting, but it doesn't seem to work.

[Here's a link to what it looks like without the layout_above setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tNSc.jpg)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your root layout is linear layout. You can't use layout_below or layout_above. Make your root layout relative layout to use it.

Comment: As per my knowledge layout_above is used when outer parent is Relative layout. In Linear Layout we need to set orientations.

Comment: If you want to set middle one Scrollable then set weightSum to root linear layout as "1" and set layout_weight to "1" for which you want that scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I made only small change in your code just paste it and try**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/profileBlock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPatientPicture"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_pic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPatientName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Anakin Skywalker" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/infoBlock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/graphInfoBlock"
    android:layout_below="@id/profileBlock"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDOB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Date of Birth: 26/08/1963" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewGender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Gender: Male" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewMedication"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Current Medication: - " />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewObservation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Observations:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewObservatonsInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mollis nulla eu scelerisque ultricies. Etiam varius iaculis purus, et ullamcorper lectus tincidunt et. Nullam vel felis eu dolor condimentum dignissim. Vestibulum in tristique nulla. Mauris elit nibh, ullamcorper in imperdiet sed, luctus vitae nibh. Aliquam nisi nisi, mattis vitae cursus id, dignissim sollicitudin risus. Nam sed egestas mauris, sed scelerisque quam. Morbi sapien turpis, vestibulum at lacus vel, lacinia vehicula elit. Maecenas et lobortis felis. Vivamus elementum ut tortor efficitur iaculis. Vestibulum vestibulum dolor ut urna facilisis eleifend. Nulla gravida mattis eros sit amet molestie. Cras pellentesque sodales tortor, id efficitur neque ultrices at. Pellentesque lacus quam, euismod a dui et, ullamcorper luctus magna. Mauris semper sem vel neque hendrerit, hendrerit elementum nibh sodales." />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graphInfoBlock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/graphPressure"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="275dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewGraphValues"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked perfectly! :)

Just to clarify, I tried using a RelativeLayout before, that's why I had layout_above and layout_below on some LinearLayouts.

Comment: @MasterExcrement Happy to help. Please remove attributes which are not usable with LinearLayout. It will create problem if you want to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Make your root layout RelativeLayout in order to use layout_above or layout_below and adjust position of your views or layouts with RelativeLayout attributes. As per my knowledge you can't use layout_above or such kind of attributes in LinearLayout.

Comment: please explain your answer or just write your answer to the post comment..

Comment: Just to clarify, I did use a RelativeLayout beforehand, and tried to switch it to Linear Layout to see if it solved it, with no success. That why some of those attributes are there

Comment: When use relative layout what problems did you have? Did you have any error?

Comment: Yeah, the long text section would overlap the graphInfoBlock LinearLayout

Comment: you should make middle scrollview height fixed for example 200dp in order not to overlap

Answer (score 0):

Replace your with below:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPatientPicture"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_pic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPatientName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Anakin Skywalker" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/infoBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/graphInfoBlock"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileBlock"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDOB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Date of Birth: 26/08/1963" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewGender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Gender: Male" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewMedication"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Current Medication: - " />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewObservation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Observations:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewObservatonsInput"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mollis nulla eu scelerisque ultricies. Etiam varius iaculis purus, et ullamcorper lectus tincidunt et. Nullam vel felis eu dolor condimentum dignissim. Vestibulum in tristique nulla. Mauris elit nibh, ullamcorper in imperdiet sed, luctus vitae nibh. Aliquam nisi nisi, mattis vitae cursus id, dignissim sollicitudin risus. Nam sed egestas mauris, sed scelerisque quam. Morbi sapien turpis, vestibulum at lacus vel, lacinia vehicula elit. Maecenas et lobortis felis. Vivamus elementum ut tortor efficitur iaculis. Vestibulum vestibulum dolor ut urna facilisis eleifend. Nulla gravida mattis eros sit amet molestie. Cras pellentesque sodales tortor, id efficitur neque ultrices at. Pellentesque lacus quam, euismod a dui et, ullamcorper luctus magna. Mauris semper sem vel neque hendrerit, hendrerit elementum nibh sodales." />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/graphInfoBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/graphPressure"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="275dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewGraphValues"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you forgot to keep '+' sign in between @ & id.

Comment: You start with a ScrollView element, but don't close it.
I tried closing it at the end, but got the same solution as before

Answer (score 0):

Try this...It will work..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPatientPicture"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_pic3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPatientName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Anakin Skywalker" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/infoBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/profileBlock"
        android:layout_above="@id/graphInfoBlock"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <!-- -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDOB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Date of Birth: 26/08/1963" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewGender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Gender: Male" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewMedication"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Current Medication: - " />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewObservation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Observations:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewObservatonsInput"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mollis nulla eu scelerisque ultricies. Etiam varius iaculis purus, et ullamcorper lectus tincidunt et. Nullam vel felis eu dolor condimentum dignissim. Vestibulum in tristique nulla. Mauris elit nibh, ullamcorper in imperdiet sed, luctus vitae nibh. Aliquam nisi nisi, mattis vitae cursus id, dignissim sollicitudin risus. Nam sed egestas mauris, sed scelerisque quam. Morbi sapien turpis, vestibulum at lacus vel, lacinia vehicula elit. Maecenas et lobortis felis. Vivamus elementum ut tortor efficitur iaculis. Vestibulum vestibulum dolor ut urna facilisis eleifend. Nulla gravida mattis eros sit amet molestie. Cras pellentesque sodales tortor, id efficitur neque ultrices at. Pellentesque lacus quam, euismod a dui et, ullamcorper luctus magna. Mauris semper sem vel neque hendrerit, hendrerit elementum nibh sodales." />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/graphInfoBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/graphPressure"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="275dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewGraphValues"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So, I tried this solution and had the same error that is shown in the end.
I did have a root RelativeLayout beforehand, but tried using a LinearLayout to see if it worked, but didn't